# how to import external js file when using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to front-end dev and am trying to write an `onClick()` function for an element. However, the `js` file where the function lies seems not imported. I've followed some instructions to modify the orders, but unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem.

### index.html

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="javascript" href="../js/jquery-1.11.0.js">
    <link type="javascript" href="../js/index.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
```

```html
<nav id="sideBarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block sidebar collapse">
    <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
        <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center text-muted ps-2">
            <span> Personal Notification </span>
        </h6>
        <ul class="nav flex-column mb-2">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="showRsvs()">
                My Reservations
            </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

### index.js

```js
$(function(){
    // refresh time every seconds
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#clock").html(getTime());
    }, 1000);
})

function showRsvs(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

Both of the functions in this file are not functioning. And I can't see the `js` folder in `Source` panel of my broswer.

### Console output

`Uncaught ReferenceError: showRsvs is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the include `js` from the `head`, `<link>` tag is used to include `css` files, `<script>` tag is used for `js` files.

After `</nav>`, where `nav` ends insert these two lines

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="../js/index.js"></script>
```

You are good to go

Comment: Thank you so much for saving my day! (though it's already been night here)

Comment: haha, glad that worked